Vee-validate - how to get all dirty fields
In my vue project I'm doing form validation with the help of vee-validate, primarily using useForm. One handy feature is the meta object, which has the dirty flag, indicating if any field has changed from its initial value.
Since I'm handling quite big forms with deep object schemas, I want to restrict the data for update requests to the fields that are actually updated - meaning that every field that has not changed is to be ditched from the final values object. I figured it would be doable by filtering the fields individually by their dirty flags, but I'm a bit lost since useForm does not seem to provide a way to iterate through all fields or look up if any of those are dirty. There only seems to be the aggregated meta object.
How would one using useForm be able to find out which values have actually changed in the form, not only for flat but also for nested object schemas?
